# Remove file from github

Tags: python, github

I need your help.

I just remove a file (Python 1D MEM.ipynb) from local (My PC) since my written code was messy.
Then I downloaded that file (Python 1D MEM.ipynb) from my Github to the PC as my backup.
the problem is the oversize file (Automated 1D MEM.ipynb) of my previous uploaded. So I got this message and being unable to upload a new one (Python 1D MEM.ipynb).

PS. Python 1D MEM.ipynb and Automated 1D MEM.ipynb are the same file, just renamed.
And I prefer to use a new one (Python 1D MEM.ipynb).

How do I solve this. I just want to remove the old one (Automated 1D MEM.ipynb) on remote.
and upload a new one (Python 1D MEM.ipynb) instead.

```
(datascience) D:\Github\1D MEM>git push -f origin master
warning: redirecting to https://github.com/phumikrai/1D-MEM.git/
Enumerating objects: 102, done.
Counting objects: 100% (101/101), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (96/96), done.
Writing objects: 100% (96/96), 56.96 MiB | 1.62 MiB/s, done.
Total 96 (delta 46), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (46/46), completed with 1 local object.
remote: warning: File Automated 1D MEM.ipynb is 82.49 MB; this is larger than GitHub's recommended maximum file size of 50.00 MB
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.
remote: error: Trace: df632e0207decf41410cbccae69ce3b6826362c5a1b26e0a195fa50d81b3ebed
remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.
remote: error: File Python 1D MEM.ipynb is 100.75 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
To http://github.com/phumikrai/1D-MEM.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'http://github.com/phumikrai/1D-MEM.git'
```

Answer (score 0):

IPython notebook files are somewhat akin to word documents: they get very large, and aren't actually able to be properly line-diffed due to being largely binary (read: not human-readable). Instead, I recommend backing up these notebooks in a cloud storage service like Google Drive and OneDrive. Those services also have versioning support that can be set up.

Clearly this is a very large python notebook if it has 100MB of information. Git isn't designed to handle these types of files.